# Accessing a Div's child elements in a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a form builder, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about creating new elements, and accessing the elements inside those.

Let's say I have this:

```
<div id="Group1"><div id="targetField"></div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div id="targetField"></div></div>
```

I want to access **Group2**'s targetField. How could I specify that I want to get that ID? Or can't this be done using ID's with the same name?

---

*I have tried doing a specific path, but I don't think this is possible, as I'm getting an error.*

```
var parentDOM = document.getElementById('Group2');
var target=parentDOM.getElementById('targetField');
```

---

Comment: You should not be using same `id` for two or more elements. You have multiple elements with `targetField` id. It is a bad practice.

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique therefore `getElementById` will only return the first element it comes across with the stated id - also clue is in the name - get element (single) by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `id` should never be repeated on the same page, period. `id` is meant to be a wholly unique identifier. (While some browsers will let you get away with it, it'll cause unexpected and inconsistent behaviors).

Instead of using name, if they are the same type of thing, the more appropriate option would be to specify it as a `class` instead:

```
<div id="Group1"><div class="targetField"></div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div class="targetField"></div></div>
```

After that, it is trivial to get the appropriate element:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#Group2 .targetField');
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="Group1"><div class="targetField">A</div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div class="targetField">B</div></div>
```

Basically, just use `document.querySelector()` and give it a selector (same format as CSS selectors) to the element in question.

Comment: Thank you, this was very clear and helpful. I know it may be a trivial question, but sometimes we're just too tired or overly obsessed with other parts of the code to see the answer for ourselves, or maybe that just happens to me, considering the downvotes.

Comment: I think there are some people that are a little too trigger happy when it comes to downvotes. While it may be a "basic" question, I don't think it there was anything wrong with the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

An `id` must be unique in a document. Use `class` is you want arbitrary groups of elements.

```js
var parentDOM = document.getElementById('Group2');
var target = parentDOM.querySelector('.targetField');
target.style.border = "solid blue 1px";
```

```html
<div id="Group1">
  <div class="targetField">1</div>
</div>
<div id="Group2">
  <div class="targetField">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access them using `querySelector` (**I would highly recommend against that**)

```
console.log( document.querySelector( "#Group1 #targetField" ).innerHTML );

console.log( document.querySelector( "#Group2 #targetField" ).innerHTML );
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log( document.querySelector( "#Group1 #targetField" ).innerHTML );

console.log( document.querySelector( "#Group2 #targetField" ).innerHTML );
```

```html
<div id="Group1"><div id="targetField">1</div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div id="targetField">2</div></div>
```

Or you can change the `id` attribute to `data-id` attribute

```
<div id="Group1"><div data-id="targetField">1</div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div data-id="targetField">2</div></div>
```

and access it as

```
console.log( document.querySelector( "#Group1 div[data-id='targetField']" ).innerHTML );
```

> I have tried doing a specific path, but I don't think this is
>   possible, as I'm getting an error.
>
> `var parentDOM = document.getElementById('Group2');`
>
> `var target=parentDOM.getElementById('targetField');`

`getElementById` is a method of `document` only, not for any other `HTMLElement` hence you are getting an error.

But if you already have access the `Group2`, access its child element via `querySelector`

```
console.log( parentDOM.querySelector( "#targetField" ).innerHTML );
```

**Demo**

```js
var parentDOM = document.getElementById('Group2');

console.log( parentDOM.querySelector( "#targetField" ).innerHTML );
```

```html
<div id="Group1"><div id="targetField">1</div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div id="targetField">2</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't duplicate IDs.

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on your needs. Below are a couple of examples.

- If you know the order of the divs inside the parent div:

```js
var parentDOM = document.getElementById('Group2');
var target= parentDOM.children[0];
console.log(target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="Group1"><div id="targetField"></div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div id="targetField">hi there</div></div>
```

- If you just know the name of the target id:

```js
var parentDOM = document.getElementById('Group2');
var target=parentDOM.querySelector('#targetField');
console.log(target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="Group1"><div id="targetField"></div></div>
<div id="Group2"><div id="targetField">hi there</div></div>
```

Again: **DON'T DUPLICATE IDS**. Use Classes if you want multiple things of the same name. It is better practice.